# Show link to add menu

Tags: menus

I'm using the following to show a menu

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'topheader' ) ) {
    // User has assigned menu to this location;
    // output it
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'topheader',
        'menu_class'    => 'topMenu', /* bootstrap ul */
        'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu(), /* changes to a bootstrap class */
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'menu_id' => 'topMenu'
    ) );
}
```

If there are no links in the menu, nothing shows in the front-end. Is it possible to display a link to add a menu? Which takes the user to the menu location in dashboard.

Comment: have you considered the customizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible:

```
    if (has_nav_menu('topheader')) {
        // User has assigned menu to this location;
        // output it
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'topheader',
            'menu_class' => 'topMenu', /* bootstrap ul */
            'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu(), /* changes to a bootstrap class */
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'menu_id' => 'topMenu'
        ));
    }else{
        if (is_user_logged_in()) { //we check if the user is logged in
            echo '<a href="/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=0">Add New Menu</a>';
        }
    }
```

this will open the menu dashboard ready to create a new menu.

Comment: Better to use `admin_url(nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=0)` to retrieve the admin url. The user could have a custom structure and not the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the url like this: `admin_url('nav-menus.php')`

I search a lot to find a better way, through WordPress API, but I couldn't find a proper function. I took a look into [WordPress core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/nav-menus.php) and they use the same way to retrieve the menu location url.

I tried the [`menu_page_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/menu_page_url) function but I can't get it work inside a theme. I get a `Call to undefined function menu_page_url()` error.

Also [this](https://www.mightyminnow.com/2013/12/how-to-get-urls-for-wordpress-admin-menu-items/) might help. Haven't test it.